# Python version dependent type annotations

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

### Problem:

I want to use type annotation for `collections.deque`, but since we have to support older python version (3.4 and 3.5, which to be exact - and doesn't matter that they are not *officially* supported), I want my code to be valid in all python version we have to support.

My original code:

```
from collections import deque
from typing import Deque
a = deque() # type: Deque[int]
```

it works just fine in 3.7, but in 3.5, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Deque'`.

### What I tried:

so I was thinking of modifying it like this:

```
from typing import Sequence
try:
    from typing import Deque
except ImportError:
    Deque = Sequence

from collections import deque
a = deque() # type: Deque[int]
```

But then I get errors:

```
$ mypy . --pretty
a.py:5: error: Cannot assign multiple types to name "Deque" without an explicit "Type[...]" annotation
    Deque = Sequence
    ^
a.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Sequence[Any]]", variable has
type "Type[deque[Any]]")
    Deque = Sequence
        ^
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

### Question:

Is there a way of having the same code which would be valid even in python3.4 and python3.5 while having type annotation for deque?

### Note:

Yes, I know 3.4 and 3.5 are not officially suported. But that fact does not help me at all. Please don't tell me to upgrade.

Comment: Any class can be annotated as a string. Therefore to annotate a variable called X as a Deque Collection then you can `X: "deque" = deque()`

Comment: @thethiny that's true (although I'd have to write `X = deque() # type: deque` for py3.4 compatibility), but I won't get "inside type" (`int` in the question's example) information and type checking..

Comment: I'm unsure about the nested type as usually I'd write it as "deque(int)" but in your case it won't work. However what you can do is define a new implementation of Deque (or sequence or collection) from Typing as a variable `something = Sequence(int)` and use `something` as your type. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type checkers use their own version of `typing` features, regardless whether the runtime `typing` library supports them. A type such as `Deque[int]` can be used freely for checking in any version as long as it is not used at runtime.

- If the `typing` module is available on all desired version, [guard the imports](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING):

  ```py
  from collections import deque
  from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
  if TYPE_CHECKING:             # not entered at runtime
      from typing import Deque  # only happens during static type checking

  a = deque() # type: Deque[int]
  ```

  The `typing` module can be added to pre-3.5 version as [a backport](https://pypi.org/project/typing/).
- The general solution for versions not supporting all required type features are [`pyi` stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files).

  ```py
  # a.py
  from collections import deque

  a = deque()
  ```

  ```py
  # a.pyi
  from typing import Deque

  a: Deque[int] = ...
  ```

Comment: The problem is NOT availability of type checking - we were using typing even for older py2 versions - but specially `Deque` is not available in typing for python3.5 (I assume you can't install newest typing module on older python versions).

Comment: @JanSpurny How does that relate to the content of the answer? It is not claiming the problem would be the availability of type checking.

Comment: oh, I did not know what TYPE_CHECKING did and somehow expected it just meant "type checking is available". Thanks!

Comment: @JanSpurny Thanks for the feedback. I've added a comment in the code to clarify that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this (or a variation of it) would work

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3,7):
    from typing import Deque
else:
    from typing import Sequence as Deque

from collections import deque    
a = deque() # type: Deque[int]
```